# Is it possible to apply textures of different color to a surface on each side? blender 2.9

Tags: texturing

As stated I was wondering if it was possible to put a texture of a different colour on the the other side of a surface.  If one side is the external surface, and the other the internal, can this be done without extra geometry.  It seems as if it should be. Blender 2.9.

I tried adding these nodes together as mentioned in the comments but I am obviously doing something wrong.

[image: double sided node setup for adding - failed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *"backfacing"* from the [*"geometry"* node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html):

[image]

Here is something closer to your setting:

[image]

Comment: I have updated a node-image but have not managed to apply the setup. What is necessary in my setup, thanks.

Comment: Place the mix color node before the shader, not after. And keep the mix color node to "mix", not "add".